# How to hide a <div> with media queries?

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries

I'm trying to hide a certain div element  only on my ipad and mobile versions of my site.
I have it hidden but it's not really "gone" if that makes sense? it's position is till taken just invisible.
Is there a way to completely remove it on mobile and ipad so that my text re-position itself on those platforms?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using "display:none" and not "visibility:hidden"?

Comment: I'm using "display:none" Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Below are list of standard media queries for devices

```
/* Large screens ----------- */
/*some CSS*/

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1824px) {...}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1224px) {...}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {...}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {...}

/* Big smartphones (portrait) (ie: Galaxy 3 has 360)*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {...}

/* Smartphones (portrait) (ie: Galaxy 1) */
@media only screen and (max-width : 321px) {...}
```

as per your requirement within these blocks you need to add CSS as follows

```
.foo{display:none;} /* foo is class of element you need to hide*/
```

either you can use `display:none` or visually hide as follows

```
.visuallyhidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
```

**[useful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301680/responsive-design-standard-breakpoint-media-queries-for-smartphone-and-tablet)**

**[CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I know how to use the media queries to hide it, The problem I'm encountering is that after I use "display:none" it makes it invisible but it does not actually remove it. So I cannot position my text on the page where it should be in the center of the page. It shoves it over..

Comment: can you show page URL/ jsfiddle etc where this is happening

Answer (score 0):

You must use `.divclass{display:none;}` display none will hide your DOM elements to browser.No evidence of block there.

Eventually visibility property
    `.divclass{ visibility:invisible; }` only hides DOM element to Users. Blank Space Background will be displayed instead of that block.